# Writing program to get datatypes of certain fields and then do some work on that but SearchCursor makes everything tuples

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, cursor, python-toolbox

I am trying to write a program to get the datatypes of certain fields and then do some work on that but SearchCursor makes everything tuples.

How do I bypass this situation and get the actual datatype of the field in question?

Code added in below:

```py
ingdb1 = parameters[0].valueAsText
field1 = parameters[1].valueAsText
ingdb2 = parameters[2].valueAsText
field2 = parameters[3].valueAsText
outField = parameters[4].valueAsText

arcpy.env.workspace=r'C:\Users\JKart\Desktop\GDB Files\d43w3.gdb'
f1type=''
f2type=''
f1=arcpy.da.SearchCursor(ingdb1,[field1])
f2=arcpy.da.SearchCursor(ingdb2,[field2])
for a in f1:
    for b in f2:
        f1type=type(a)
        f2type=type(b)
        # f1type=arcpy.Describe(f1).type
        # f2type=arcpy.Describe(f2).type
        break
    break
arcpy.AddMessage('field1 type: '+str(f1type))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `arcpy.ListFields()` to get all sorts of information about fields, including the field types.  See:  https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-functions/listfields.htm

One you have your list of field objects, you just query the `type` property, of each field object to find out its type.  See:  https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-classes/field.htm

You could use these something like the following:

```py
for theField in arcpy.ListFields(SomeFeatureClass):
    arcpy.AddMessage('{}: {}'.format(theField.name, theField.type))
```